# windows batch script to combine multiple rows to a comma separated single row

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have text file like below strings in multiple rows

```
1234
234545
123
16322
```

I need a output like using windows batch script

```
1234,234545,123,16322
```

Comment: You could also use a program like Notepad++ to replace "\r\n" with ",". Not a batch answer, but this is very useful for one off situations.

Comment: `for /f %i in (test1.txt) do set /p=%i, <nul`: transpose single column to (comma separated) single row

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "txt="
set input=input.txt
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%input%) do (
  set "txt=!txt!%%a,"
)
set "txt=!txt:~0,-1!"
>new.txt echo !txt!
```